# CSS Formating, Borders Won't Go Full Length

Tags: css

I know that this has been addressed in many places, but the template I modified was a bit quirky and I believe that I know what is causing the problem. I just don't know what to do to fix it.

The template sets the `left` and `right borders` to 200px. I think what it needed to do was make 2 more columns instead of a border that size. I want the partial grey lines on the sides of the page to go all the way down but they don't. I know it's because the content doesn't go all the way down, but for the life of me I can't figure out what to do with this. Should I just start this all over from scratch?

I apologize ahead of time for the page quality it just has random information in it to hold places.

link to page
[Site](http://www.trihelios.com)

```
#container {
width: 950px;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:100%;
} 
#banner {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #E39A2D;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


/ here is where it goes a little wrong*/
#outer{ 
border-left: solid 200px #E39A2D; 
border-right: solid 200px #E39A2D;
background-color: #ffffff;  
height:100%;
} 

#inner{margin:0; width:100%; height:100%; } 
#left {
 width:200px; 
 float:left; 
 position:relative; 
 margin-left:-200px; 
 margin-right:1px;
 border-left:2px solid #564b47;
  height:inherit;
  }
 #right {
 width:200px; 
 float:right; 
 position:relative; 
 margin-right:-200px; 
 margin-left:1px;
 border-right:2px solid #564b47;
 height:inherit;

  }
#content{ 
position: relative; 
margin: 0px; 
height:150%;
}
```

I'm not looking to make it full page length that I know how to do. I'm just looking to extend the lines all the way down the left and right sides.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The borders you want to edit are the ones from the #outer div:

```
#outer{ 
border-left: solid 200px #564B47; 
border-right: solid 200px #564B47;
}
```

Anyway your code seems a bit weird, using borders for layout is not the right way to go and it will give you problems. Check this out: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Im sorry i should have added that i wanted t leave the white header sides at the top free and clear. I wanted to only box in the middle sides and not the top header area as well.

Comment: Now that I look at it closely, are you having a 200px border? That's not a good way of doing what you want